# cannot load such file -- /vagrant_data/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, rake, bundle, unicorn

On vagrant, I tried to set up db, however it returned the following error. 

`[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 vagrant_data]$ bundle exec rake db:setup
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /vagrant_data/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/version`

I've checked `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/`, then it has `unicorn-5.0.1`.
I'm not sure why this error occurs. Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Is `vagrant_data` a synced folder ?

Comment: are you using `rvm`?

Comment: @ValterHenrique Yes.

Comment: @tokhi No. I'm using rbenv.

Comment: myabe make sure that you have only one ruby installation and you are using ruby via `rbenv` and not the ruby from the system.

Comment: Please, try to move your project inside of the VM filesystem. What I'm saying is for you to give a try into NOT using synced folders. I had some issues with this feature during my development.

Comment: @ValterHenrique   Does it mean, I should remove this  cdoe `config.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/vagrant_data"` from Vagrantfile?